# Issue with successful 1-to-many merge on primary key

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, merge

I have 2 dataframes where df1 has 1 instance of the primary key 'CUID' and df2 has 12 instances of 'CUID'.

df1 has many column fields that I need, and df2 has 2 columns, 'CUID' and 'Value' and 'Month'.

I would like to keep all the column values from df1 and repeat them for each month with the associated 'Value'.

An example:

**df1**

| CUID | x | y | z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 | 2 | 3 |

**df2**

| CUID | Value | Month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 500 | 1 |
| 123 | 300 | 2 |
| 123 | 500 | 3 |
| 123 | 100 | 4 |
| 123 | 700 | 5 |
| 123 | 500 | 6 |
| 123 | 500 | 7 |
| 123 | 500 | 8 |
| 123 | 500 | 9 |
| 123 | 500 | 10 |
| 123 | 500 | 11 |
| 123 | 500 | 12 |

**Goal df**

| CUID | x | y | z | Value | Month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 500 | 1 |
| 123 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 300 | 2 |
| 123 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 500 | 3 |
| 123 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 100 | 4 |
| 123 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 700 | 5 |
| 123 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 500 | 6 |
| 123 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 500 | 7 |
| 123 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 500 | 8 |
| 123 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 500 | 9 |
| 123 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 500 | 10 |
| 123 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 500 | 11 |
| 123 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 500 | 12 |

I tried outer merge but am not sure if it is correctly doing what I want. If anyone has advice on how to get this I would greatly appreciate it

I tried the proposed solutions in the comments and the main issue I am having is that I need to keep all ID's that are present in both df's. There are some keys that are not present in the other. So that is why I was looking at the outer join. But when I do this, it only grabs month 1.

### This grabs all the columns but only keeps month 1

df_personnel_data = pd.merge(df1, df2, how = "left", on='CUID')

### This deletes CUID's that are not present in both, and it also doesn't have all months

df_personnel_data = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='CUID')

### This grabs all Cuids even if not present in df2, but only grabs month 1 for those that are present in both

df_personnel_data = pd.merge(df1, df2, how = 'outer', on='CUID')

### This does the same thing as above

df_personnel_data = pd.merge(df2, df1, how = 'outer', on='CUID')

Comment: What is wrong with merge? `df2.merge(df1, on='CUID')`

Comment: `df2.merge(df1,how='left',on='CUID')`?

Comment: I tried these and the main issue I am having is that I need to keep all ID's that are present in both df's. There are some keys that are not present in the other. So that is why I was looking at the outer join. But when I do this, it only grabs month 1.

Comment: @It_is_Chris do you know this exception?

Comment: @ek11222 what do you mean by "it only grabs month 1" when you do an outer join?